# validate a localhost:xxxx link in php laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4

i have the method:

```
public function getAppLink($app_path)
{
    if( ! $this->isAppExists($app_path)) { return false; }
    $content = $this->getContent();

    // make sure that the link is available
    $validate_link = \Validator::make(
        ['app_link' => $content->apps->$app_path->link],
        ['app_link' => 'active_url']
    );

    if($validate_link->fails())
    {
        $this->setAppStatus($app_path, 'stopped');
        $this->setAppLink($app_path, 'invalid_link');

        return '';
    }
    else {
        $this->setAppStatus($app_path, 'started');
        return $content->apps->$app_path->link;
    }
}
```

i need to validate that `localhost:xxxx` link is active and can be accessed via the browser, before returning it.

somehow the laravel way of testing link is not working, am i doing this wrong, or i need to use a different approach?

note: xxxx is the port number

Comment: Is what you have posted “the laravel way”? And what does “is not working” mean?

Comment: @DourHighArch what i need is just to validate that a link to <code>localhost:port_number</code> can be accessed via the browser

Answer (score 2):

The Laravel `active_url` Validator is just a wrapper around the PHP [`checkdnsrr`](http://php.net/checkdnsrr) function.  The purpose of this function is solely to check for DNS records, not to actually check if the server is responding.

Because you are on `localhost`, there are no DNS records so this check would not work.

If you want to check that a link can be accessed by the *browser*, you have to do that in JavaScript on the browser.  Otherwise, you could have a case where `http://localhost:1234` is accessible from the server but is not accessible from the browser because of the firewall or because the webserver is only listening on `127.0.0.1` and not on all IP addresses.  *While this will obviously work properly as long as you are doing all of your development on your local computer, it may cause you problems in production (depending, of course, on exactly what it is that you need this information for).*

If you actually want to check whether the site is up, just do a CURL GET (or HEAD) request to the URL.

An easy way to use CURL in Laravel is with [this composer package](https://github.com/jyggen/curl).  The full documentation is too long to put here, but you can find it [here](https://github.com/jyggen/docs/blob/master/curl/overview.md).

Comment: all i need is just to check if localhost:1234 can be accessible from the browser, or not, i've used fsockopen, and get_headers, but somehow it gives me a weird fatal error, that why am trying laravel instead, and here i am, i will test curl from the provided link, tnx for taking time to reply.

Answer (score 1):

i solved this problem by using fsockopen:

```
// ==================================================== isLinkValid()
//
// $link : the link you want to validate, ex: localhost:1234
//
// return true | false
//
private function isLinkValid($link)
{
    if(strpos($link, ":") === false)
    {
        return false;
    }

    $arr_link = explode(":", $link);
    $host = $arr_link[0];
    $port = $arr_link[1];

    $sock_open = @fsockopen($host, $port);

    if(is_resource($sock_open))
    {
        fclose($sock_open);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Note that this still does not check if the link is accessible from the *browser*, only if it is accessible from the *server*. Since your server and browser are currently on the same computer, this should work for you for now, but as soon as you move the application to a real server this isn't necessarily going to work anymore.

Comment: @MosheKatz it's true, i want the validation only from the server side, of course for the client, there is more simpler way using javascript.